# Accessing a var assigned inside a try block throws Error : Unknown code ref type given error ''. Check your usage and try again

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out why that error is thrown here. Shouldn't it just print 0 provided something wrong happens inside the try block and print 10 otherwise ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;

my $test = 0;
try{
    $test = 10;
    my $s = $test /2;
}
catch{
    print $_;
}

print $test;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a ; after the try/catch "statement"; your code is passing the result of the `print $test` as an extra parameter to catch where it is expecting a finally clause and dies before it even gets into the try block.

Comment: I see. Didn't know that a ; needs to be put after the catch block. I was using it as i use try catch in Java! My bad. works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @user2148105, `try` is just a function exported by Try::Tiny. It's not a statement, so a `;` is required.